# Motion of sphere on horiztonal plane with prescribed motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

I was wondering about this simple problem.

A sphere sits on an (infinite) horizontal plane. Starting from $t = 0$, the plate is assigned a known motion in terms of horizontal velocity $u = f(t)$. Assume no slip of the sphere, then what is its motion?[image: illustration]

All I could found was the velocity constraint:

$$\dot x + r \dot \phi = f(t)$$

Imagine a simple case where $f(t) = 1$, I can imagine two limit cases

1. $\dot x  =1$ and $\dot \phi = 0$, the sphere sits quietly without
   rotation, and is dragged by the plate
2. $\dot x  =0$ and $\dot \phi = 1$, the sphere rotates locally but does not shift

That makes me wonder if this question is actually ill posed. Any toughts?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *under-constrained*. There are 2 independent variables $(\dot x, \dot \phi)$ but only one equation constraining them.

Comment: Could you please give an example 2nd constraint that makes this problem solvable? Thanks.